# ¿Como puedo mostrar los datos de una tabla en otra tabla? SQL Server

Tags: php, html, sql-server

mi problema es: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ese Diagrama de entidad/relacion, donde en ciertas tablas poseo una llave foránea
Lo que quiero es poder mostrar la informacion de una tabla en otra obteniendo el Id o de ser posible el dato especifico, pero imagino que eso se hace mediante el Id.
Como se puede apreciar en el modelo, en la tabla "Usuario" tengo un campo llamado IdConfig, que proviene del Id de la tabla "Configuracion" pero no logro recuperar el Id (configuracion) en IdConfig (Usuario), y tampoco logro que se muestre...
La idea es que al imprimir los datos de la tabla Usuario pueda ver lo que se eligio en configuracion pero claro, eso sera de acuerdo al usuario ya que cuando se registre un usuario tendra que mostrar lo que ese usuario en el registro eligio en configuracion

Comment: La parte que no entiendo es "Lo que quiero es poder mostrar la informacion de una tabla en otra " . ¿estas intentando obtener la info en una consulta ? Muestra como estas tratando de obtener la info , y si puedes poner captura de tus datos en las tablas mucho mejor

Comment: @elierickdevelopment Claro, la idea es hacer un formulario en html y php de registrar datos y luego mostrarlos, algo que si pude hacer, mi problema como comentaba es lo mismo que me preguntas, quiero obternet el ID de una tabla, en ese caso, configuracion y poder mostrarla en la tabla Usuario ya que en IdConfig (Usuario) es una llave foranea vinculada al Id de configuracion...

Comment: Amigo, porfa muestra un ejemplo de los datos que deseas obtener

Answer (score 2):

Creo que hay un error en la forma en la que quieres solucionarlo. En tu lugar, yo primero cambiaria el nombre de los id (porque esto puede traerte problemas mas adelante) por ejemplo, id_usu, id_config.

Por otra parte, te faltaría añadir un campo a la tabla configuracion donde vas a cargar el id del usuario a la que está relacionada esa configuaracion. ej "id_usu_config". y añadiria a la tabla usuario un disparador after, update,

BEGIN
INSERT INTO configuracion( id_usu_cofig)
VALUES (OLD.id_usu);
END

No estoy segura de que esta sea la mejor solucion para ti, pero espero aportarte algo.

Comment: En teoria, quiero cargar el ID de configuracion en el "IdConfig" de usuario, y poder mostrar los datos, respecto a "BEGIN INSERT INTO configuracion( id_usu_cofig) VALUES (OLD.id_usu); END" que hace este fragmento de codigo? Soy nuevo en sql y la verdad apenas se cosas esenciales...

Comment: Es decir, que en configuracion tu tienes una lista de "configuraciones" predeterminadas. Donde el usuario desde su perfil va a poder seleccionar una de las opcion de tu lista? Es asi? Por favor, si cargas mayor informacion sobre tu problema y un fragmento del codigo que tiene el problema, nos ayudaría a poder apoyarte.